# in matlab in fsolve we define x0, can I use range for x0?

Tags: matlab

```
myfun = @(x)[x(1)^2/4+x(2)^2/16-1;
cos(x(1)*5)/sqrt(x(2))-x(1)];
x0 = [a; b]; 
options=optimset('Display','iter'); [x,fval,exitflag]=fsolve(myfun,x0,options)
```

such that `2.3>a>0` and `1.2>b>0`

can I extend the number of iterations?

Comment: ```x0``` is probably called **starting-point**. So what would you think about your idea in this case? Not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want a multi-start feature, encapsulate your opt-problem and call it multiple-times with different x0's (with randomy-sampled values or a cartesian-product of your dimensions after some coarse discretization).

Comment: If you're interested in knowing why `fsolve()` is iterating a certain number of times (even though you aren't explicitly telling it to, refer to this [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/tolerances-and-stopping-criteria.html): `The number of iterations in an optimization depends on a solver's *stopping criteria*.` Essentially, `fsolve()` reached one of the function evaluation, step, or optimality tolerances. If you want to change the number of iterations, perhaps the best way (without editing the tolerances themselves) is to "guess" a different starting point, `x0`.

Comment: In regards to number of iterations, you should always check the state of the optimizer after optimizing. Observing some state like ```maximum number of iterations reached``` always calls for a different parameterization (e.g. increasing the upper-limit) or reformulation of the problem.